# SonarQube cloud for swift not showing any warning for force unwrap

Tags: swift, sonarqube

We are trying SonarQube cloud for swift to verify if it's giving a warning for force unwrap.

Its showing other bugs, code smells properly but not showing anything for force unwrap.

So can anyone confirm if cloud version supports warning/bugs for force unwrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rule "Optionals should not be force-unwrapped" with key S2966. It's not activated in default profile. That's why probably you don't get any issue for it.

You should create your own profile extending default one and add this rule to it.